# Establishing subset tables

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to model a workstation subject which represents two subordinate subjects that share common characteristics with the main subject. These are: desktop and laptop

Each subordinate subject contains characteristics that are germane to that particular subject and the `ws_asset_no` (PK) field that relates it to the parent subject.

```
workstation

ws_asset_no
date_issued
date_returned
operating_system

desktop

ws_asset_no
monitor_asset_no

laptop

ws_asset_no
laptop_category
```

`laptop_category` is a multivalued field that will get resolved into a table.

Can anyone please confirm that this is the right approach and advise about the relationships.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is correct and it's probably best for your scenario. Remember that ws_asset_no in tables laptop and desktop have to be both primary key and foreign key.

The alternative approaches you could take are:

- (Single Table Inheritance) put all data in table workstation, and add auxiliary column workstation_type which tells if the workstation is a laptop, or a desktop
- (Concrete Table Inheritance) have tables laptop and desktop (no table workstation) with all data for laptop and desktop.

[See this question for more details on the different approaches to database inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)